# Void is not assignable to > parameter of type '() => void'

Tags: angular, typescript, socket.io

I have an angular app which was written originally in Angular 2 then upgraded to 7 and then 9 and now trying to start with 11.

My code has a function where it gets from the back end the Notification count for the user via socket when the app is loaded initially ( code below) which worked fine but no longer does so in Angular 11. The error i am getting is

> Argument of type '(notifyCount: INotifyCount) => void' is not
> assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.ts(2345) Argument of type
> '(notifyMessage: INotification) => void' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '() => void'.ts(2345)

So i hope someone can tell me how to fix this so i can compile without error again.

```
socketInit() {
    this.socketService.ioInject('notifyCount', (notifyCount: INotifyCount) => {
        console.log('notifications count data ', notifyCount);
        this.notificationsCount = notifyCount.count;
    });
    this.socketService.ioInject('notifyMessage', (notifyMessage: INotification) => {
        console.log('notify message data ', notifyMessage);
        this.toasterService.pop('info', notifyMessage.subject, notifyMessage.message);
    });
}
```

and my socket service looks like this..

```
  ioInject(event: string, handler: () => void) {
    if (this.client) {
      this.client.on(event, handler);
    } else {
      console.warn('Socket client not initialized');
    }
  }
```

And here are my 2 clsses..

```
export interface INotification {
  DocId: string;
  user_guid: string;
  type: string;
  status: string;
  subject: string;
  message: string;
  link: string;
  created_on: string;
}

export  interface INotifyCount {
  count: number;
}
```

Comment: It's quite straightforward, it says your notify count callback requires an argument where your `ioInject` handler argument just a simple non argument taken function So when they don't match it gives you this `bla bla is not assignable with bla bla`. So either change your handler type to any or a matching pattern with your functions :)

Answer (score 0):

You must change the signature of ioInject method

```
ioInject(event: string, handler: (n: any) => void) {
    if (this.client) {
      this.client.on(event, handler);
    } else {
      console.warn('Socket client not initialized');
    }
  }
```

Comment: This violates the Open/Closed Principle. Based on the code sample, I'd guess this is a generic service where the type of object could be anything, but is based on the type of event passed in. It might be safer to use generics, or even `any` as the argument type.